# How do I create a subset using values in a list in R

Tags: r

```
df <- Make  model 
      audi   a6
      audi   a1
      merc   180
      bmw    320
      vw     golf

mylist <- (audi,bmw)
```

I am trying to create subset of df with only the values in `mylist`.

I tried this but can't get it working.

```
df1 = subset(df, model %in% mylist)
```

Please can anyone help?

Comment: `df1 = subset(df, Make %in% mylist)` ?

Comment: Note that `mylist` is actually a vector and should be coded as `mylist <- c("audi", "bmw")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating your data...

```
#Create Data
df <- data.frame("Make" = c("audi", "audi", "merc", "bmw","vw"), 
                 "model" = c("a6","a1","180","320","golf"))

df
#   Make model
# 1 audi    a6
# 2 audi    a1
# 3 merc   180
# 4  bmw   320
# 5   vw  golf

# Create a vector
mylist <- c("audi","bmw")
```

You can use the default `subset` function.

```
# Subset
subset(df,Make %in% mylist)
#   Make model
# 1 audi    a6
# 2 audi    a1
# 4  bmw   320
```

Or try the classic `tidyverse` method using function `filter()`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(Make %in% mylist)

#   Make model
# 1 audi    a6
# 2 audi    a1
# 4  bmw   320
```